# Selenium modal xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I need to select this input ...

```
(name="BtnNext" value="İLERİ" class="NavigationButtonNextLightBox ")
```

... with xpath after this modal popup. I cant use `.FindByClass` because there are same classes in the main page, but I need open which in `(id="__LIGHTBOX__")` modal;

---

```
<div style="overflow: visible; padding: 0px; width: auto; min-height: 143px; max-height: none; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="__LIGHTBOX__">
    <div class="__BOX__">
        <input name="BtnClose" class="BoxButtonClose" type="button">
        <div>
            <img src="/Content/themes/base/images/popup-bg-top.png">
        </div>
        <div class="popupCapsule clearFix">

            <form action="/BillPayment/TransferInfo" method="post">
                <div class="banner clearFix">
                    <h1 class="pageTitle">Fatura Ödeme</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="relatedPeopleContainer clearFix">
                    <div class="topDiv">
                    </div>
                    <div class="relatedPeople clearFix">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="t1">
                                        <img src="Content/banks/bank205.png">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t2 SenderReceiverSubmit" rowspan="2" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                        <div class="arrow">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t3">
                                        <img src="Content/company/Turkcell.png">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="t4">
                                        <div class="info right">
                                            <h2 class="NavigationButtonIndex" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Hesabınızı değiştirmek için tıklayınız.">HESABIM
                                <img src="/Content/themes/base/images/change-account.png" alt="" style="height: 20px; vertical-align: text-bottom;">
                                            </h2>

                                            <p class="first">
                                                Beşyüzevler Şube
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                Cari Hesap
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                10136046-1
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                1.256,51 TL
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t6">
                                        <div class="info left">
                                            <h2>TURKCELL
                                            </h2>

                                            <p class="first">
                                                1774862559
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                5303003816
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                23,40 TL
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottomDiv">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="amountEntry clearFix">
                    <table class="moneyEditorTable ">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="integerinput " data-val="true" data-val-regex="The field Integer must match the regular expression '[0-9.,]{1,11}'." data-val-regex-pattern="[0-9.,]{1,11}" datavalrequired="" disabled="disabled" id="IntegerInput" name="Amount.Integer" onkeyup=";" value="23" type="text"></td>
                                <td class="spanTd">
                                    <span class="currency ">,</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input maxlength="2" class="decimalinput  " data-val="true" data-val-range="The field Decimal must be between 0 and 99." data-val-range-max="99" data-val-range-min="0" datavalrequired="" disabled="disabled" id="DecimalInput" name="Amount.Decimal" onkeypress="return BOA.Web.Validation.NumericControl(event);" onkeyup=";BOA.Web.Validation.DecimalPoint(event, $(this));" onpaste="BOA.Web.Validation.NumericEditorPaste(event, $(this));" value="40" type="text"></td>
                                <td class="spanTd">
                                    <span class="currency ">TL</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input id="Amount_FECCode" name="Amount.FECCode" value="TL" type="hidden">

                    <div class="Error clearFix">
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Amount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="popupButtonArea">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">
                                <input name="BtnPrev" value="GERİ" class="NavigationButtonPrev " type="button">
                            </td>
                            <td class="right">
                                <input name="BtnNext" value="İLERİ" class="NavigationButtonNextLightBox " type="button">
                                <input name="FromStep" value="TransferInfo" type="hidden">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="jzI4c0v-PPC60xzaY8B2FDiCLYmHwCCtQsYv7UbBIMgnBWFeEpJoLLMDgf4LGl24WxhfizGlsqEJdjhywzgNHT785XHRzmwcU2qDyaQfSh6SajD8WKCAEq2L8CejPMJ65QL45A2" type="hidden">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="/Content/themes/base/images/popup-bg-sub.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find the element by the following xpath :

```
//div[contains(@id, 'LIGHTBOX')]//input[@name='BtnNext' and contains(@class, 'NavigationButtonNextLightBox')]
```

Above xpath attempt to find a `<div>` having id contains `LIGHTBOX`, then from within that `<div>` get `<input>` element having name attribute equals `BtnNext` and class attribute contains `NavigationButtonNextLightBox`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure am i missing somehting here, but whats stopping you from selecting by name?

```
WebElement btnNext = driver().findElement(By.name("BtnNext"));
```

Comment: @OP: matching on a name I think is the best specificity you can get in this instance.

Comment: yep. the preferred selector order is:  id -> name ->links text -> css -> xpath

Comment: well.. that's subjective :)  for example, I think the `title` attribute is more specific than "links text".  Also I personally use CSS for everything. even when searching for an id, i will do `cssSelector("#id")`  but to the same respect, anyone else might prefer doing `byXpath("//[@id='id']")`.  you should clarify that comment by saying "your preferred selector".  not `"the"` ;)

Comment: [Here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-id) is something from Selenium docs to (kind of) backup my statement. Id is generally regarded as the most efficient selector.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that id "wasn't" regarded as the most efficient selector `:)`  I just don't want the OP misled by thinking that the order you just gave is "the" preferred selector.  I'm actually [a maintainer (ddavison)](https://github.com/orgs/SeleniumHQ/people#org-members) of Selenium documentation, and I could change the documentation of what I think is most efficient, but I won't because it's what *i* think `;)`  the issue isn't with id.  it's with the rest of the line down after ID.  it's subjective, and the OP shouldn't consider what you said, as "the" preferred selector.  that's it

Comment: Ah cool, guess we were on different pages. I agree that is subjective. @OP, the above list is my preferred selector order :-)

Comment: with that said, you do have the correct answer, which is why i upvoted `:)`